# What does "I've mortgaged all my castles in the air" mean?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

From the lyrics of "[Everything happens to me](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/ellafitzgerald/everythinghappenstome.html)", what do these 2 lines mean?

1. > At first my heart thought you could break this jinx for me
   > That love would turn the trick to end despair
   > But now I just can't fool this head that thinks for me
   > **I've mortgaged all my castles in the air**
2. > I never miss a thing
   > I've had the measles and the mumps
   > **And every time I play an ace
   >
   > My partner always trumps**

Answer (score 1):

A "castle in the air" is a dream, a fancy.  [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/castles-in-the-air) Dictionary gives it as

> plans that have very little chance of happening

Figuratively, he would have to have given up even on dreams (by mortgaging) because his luck is so bad.

"Play an ace" and "trumps" are from bridge.  An ace is the winning card in a trick (a play) except that a trump card would defeat it -- so his ace is wasted.

Both are indicators of bad luck.